# Cohomological dimension of fundamental groups aspherical manifolds [reference request]

Tags: reference-request, manifolds, fundamental-groups, group-cohomology

I've looked in Brown's *Group Cohomology* but I can't find a reference for the following fact, as stated in [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cohomological_dimension#Examples)

> More generally, the fundamental group of a closed, connected, orientable aspherical manifold of dimension n has cohomological dimension n

Can anybody help me?

Comment: Well, I don't have my copy of the book with me at the moment, but I know that theorem is in there.

Comment: This is immediate if you know that the cohomology of a group $G$ is the same as the cohomology of a $K(G,1)$ space, since such a manifold is a $K(G,1)$ space for its fundamental group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is Proposition 8.1 in Brown's book.